# Thinking error with update statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

After I run this update statement

```
update lol as l 
set prodnr = p.prodnr
from prog as p
where  (l.ponr in ('1000') and  l.abo=p.abo and l.sto=p.sto and l.ponr=p.ponr 
and l.prodnr!=p.prodnr)
```

I would expect that the following select statement yield 0 records

```
select *
from lol l, prog p  
where (l.ponr in ('1000') and  l.abo=p.abo and l.sto=p.sto and l.ponr=p.ponr 
and l.prodnr!=p.prodnr)
```

but unfortunatelly that is not the case...
Why?

---

---

**EDIT:**
I almost went crazy.. I think, the problem was, that there are multiple records in table prog for this condition:   l.abo=p.abo and l.sto=p.sto and l.ponr=p.ponr 
and l.prodnr!=p.prodnr. After I add the following additionally condition:

```
and p.pversion notnull and p.pversion !='0' and p.pversion = l.pversion
```

so the expression looks like this:

```
update lol as l 
set prodnr = p.prodnr
from prog as p
where  (l.ponr in ('1000') and  l.abo=p.abo and l.sto=p.sto and l.ponr=p.ponr 
and l.prodnr!=p.prodnr and p.pversion notnull and p.pversion !='0' and p.pversion = l.pversion)
```

the select

```
select *
from lol l, prog p  
where (l.ponr in ('1000') and  l.abo=p.abo and l.sto=p.sto and l.ponr=p.ponr 
and l.prodnr!=p.prodnr and p.pversion notnull and p.pversion !='0' and p.pversion = l.pversion)
```

yields 0 records. So I wonder yet, if the first update really updates anything. Maybe the first founded record, which fulfills the condition '(l.ponr in ('1000') and  l.abo=p.abo and l.sto=p.sto and l.ponr=p.ponr 
and l.prodnr!=p.prodnr)'

Comment: Perhaps you need a `commit`?  I could also make up scenarios where this wouldn't occur, perhaps based on triggers, a failed update of some sort, or subsequent inserts.

Comment: Can you provide sample data that exhibit the problem?